# access denied while executing c++ source file

Tags: access-denied, dev-c++, mcafee

I am unable to execute my program which i have written on DEV-CPP IDE.
[It is showing me the following error message on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbVZe.png)

I am using this IDE since 6 months on same system,but this has happened for the first time. 
i am using McAfee anti virus software.
and [it is displaying the following message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMW6I.png)
please let me know if any other detail is required for fixing this problem

Comment: Did you click the `More...` button on the McAfee dialog to see what it says?

Comment: actually I have noticed one more thing  that whenever i use cin then only i get the above problem on using scanf my programs are working perfectly fine.

Comment: on clicking more mcAfee is diplaying a message that it has quarantined a threat

Answer (score 0):

Just add your application to the `trusted items` list

see: [this question](https://community.mcafee.com/t5/Consumer-General-Discussions/How-to-add-a-items-to-the-quot-Trusted-Items-quot-list/td-p/517079)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the compiler option to TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Profiling.
Then compile and run.

[See this->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1LDR.png)